# Bad ARGS for ufw deny

Tags: 15.10, ufw

I'm following [this instruction](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Proxy) and got the following error when trying to firewall the client. How else can I use `ufw` to get the same network behavior?

```
aborns@nautilus:~$ sudo ufw deny out eth0 1:65535/tcp
ERROR: Need 'to' or 'from' clause
```

**EDIT**

```
aborns@nautilus:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY        10.0.0.0
10.0.0.0                   DENY        Anywhere

53/udp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
3128/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
53/udp (v6)                ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
3128/tcp (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Comment: `$ ufw deny --help`
`ERROR: Bad port` -- let this be a lesson: write good CLI interfaces!

Comment: if the answer is not working or not enough pm me. I hate ufw rules :-X

Comment: Sorry @Rinzwind, I'm not sure how to private message. I tried `sudo ufw deny from 10.0.0.0 to any` but when I test with a ping to www.google.com it doesn't deny the traffic. I suppose I'm not sure what my command in the OP is doing...

Comment: @AaronBorns oh just like that works ;=) Can you explain what you want to do? :-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I want to accomplish the same as `ufw deny out eth0 1:65535/tcp` rule. I have `acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8` uncommented in my squid.conf

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that page is old and [community/UFW](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) page is better.  one says:

> Deny Access
>
> Deny by specific IP
>
> sudo ufw deny from
>
> example:To block packets from 207.46.232.182:
>
> ```
> sudo ufw deny from 207.46.232.182
> ```
>
> Deny by specific port and IP address
>
> ```
> sudo ufw deny from <ip address> to <protocol> port <port number>
> ```
>
> example: deny ip address 192.168.0.1 access to port 22 for all
>   protocols
>
> ```
> sudo ufw deny from 192.168.0.1 to any port 22
> ```

---

Syntax for ufw is ...

```
sudo ufw [--dry-run] [delete] [insert NUM]  allow|deny|reject|limit  
[in|out on INTERFACE] [log|log-all] [proto protocol] 
[from ADDRESS [port PORT]][to ADDRESS [port PORT]]
```

---

From this I would believe you are missing a word before ADDRESS: "from" or "to". Since [port PORT] is inside [ from|to ADDRESS [port PORT]] you probably also are missing an ADDRESS.